# Numba Typing Error: numba.cores.errors.TypingError: np.random.binomial <unknown function>(array(float64, 2d, C), float64)

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to use Numba to speedup my code but i get this following error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(np.random.binomial) found for signature:
 
 >>> <unknown function>(array(float64, 2d, C), float64)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
   - Of which 2 did not match due to:
   Overload in function 'Numpy_negative_binomial.generic': File: numba\core\typing\randomdecl.py: Line 171.
     With argument(s): '(array(float64, 2d, C), float64)':
    No match for registered cases:
     * (int64, float64) -> int64

During: resolving callee type: Function(np.random.binomial)

def train(X, y, classes, words, hidden_neurons=10, alpha=1, epochs=50000, dropout=False, dropout_percent=0.5):
    <source elided>
            negative_dropout = 1 - dropout_percent
            binomial = np.random.binomial(arr, negative_dropout)
            ^
```

This is the code snippet providing the error:

```
    for j in iter(range(epochs + 1)):

        # Feed forward through layers 0, 1, and 2
        layer_0 = X.astype(np.float64)
        layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0, synapse_0))

        if dropout:
            arr = np.ones((len(X), hidden_neurons))
            negative_dropout = 1 - dropout_percent
            binomial = np.random.binomial(arr, negative_dropout)
            layer_1 *= binomial[0] * (1.0 / negative_dropout)

        layer_2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_1, synapse_1))

        [...]
```

How do I solve this problem?